# cross compilation from ubuntu to Raspberry Pi error: undefined symbol

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, cross-platform, cross-compiling

i'm running Qt Creator 3.0.1 (Based on Qt 5.2.1 (GCC 4.8.2, 64 bit)) on Ubuntu 14.4 64bit on VirtualBox on Windows 7 64bit
I'm trying to cross compile to Raspberry Pi and run very simple program:

MainWindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected slots:
    void ButtonClicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

LinuxProject4.cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::ButtonClicked()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Hello, World!");
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("VisualGDB Qt Demo");
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
<class>MainWindow</class>
<widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<width>400</width>
<height>300</height>
</rect>
</property>
<property name="windowTitle">
<string>LinuxProject4</string>
</property>
<widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
<widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
<x>160</x>
<y>120</y>
<width>75</width>
<height>23</height>
</rect>
</property>
<property name="text">
<string>Press me</string>
</property>
</widget>
</widget>
<widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
<property name="geometry">
<rect>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<width>400</width>
<height>25</height>
</rect>
</property>
</widget>
<widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
<attribute name="toolBarArea">
<enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
</attribute>
<attribute name="toolBarBreak">
<bool>false</bool>
</attribute>
</widget>
<widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
</widget>
<layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
<resources/>
<connections>
<connection>
<sender>pushButton</sender>
<signal>clicked()</signal>
<receiver>MainWindow</receiver>
<slot>ButtonClicked()</slot>
<hints>
<hint type="sourcelabel">
<x>199</x>
<y>89</y>
</hint>
<hint type="destinationlabel">
<x>279</x>
<y>230</y>
</hint>
</hints>
</connection>
</connections>
<slots>
<slot>ButtonClicked()</slot>
</slots>
</ui>
```

OrianFirstTest.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
Project created by QtCreator 2015-04-20T19:02:59
#-------------------------------------------------

QT += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = OrianFirstTest
target.files = OrianFirstTest
target.path = /home/pi
INSTALLS = target
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += 
MainWindow.cpp 
LinuxProject4.cpp

FORMS += 
MainWindow.ui

HEADERS += 
MainWindow.h
```

Running qmake is fine and building it as well.
When I try to run it I see for a split second the GUI and I get this message on my PC:

> /home/pi/OrianFirstTest: symbol lookup error: /home/pi/OrianFirstTest: undefined symbol: _ZN7QWidget8qwsEventEP8QWSEvent
> Application finished with exit code 127.

running on Raspberry Pi: "ldd OrianFirstTest" returns: "not a dynamic executable".

Running on Raspberry Pi: "echo _ZN7QWidget8qwsEventEP8QWSEvent | c++filt" returns: "QWidget::qwsEvent(QWSEvent*)".

Running on Raspberry Pi: "readelf -d OrianFirstTest" return:

> Dynamic section at offset 0x400c contains 32 entries:
>
> Tag Type Name/Value
>
> 0x000000 01 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libQtGui.so.4]
>
> 0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libQtNetwork.so.4]
>
> 0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libQtCore.so.4]
>
> 0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
>
> 0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
>
> 0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libm.so.6]
>
> 0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
>
> 0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libc.so.6]
>
> 0x0000000f (RPATH) Library rpath: [/opt/qt/lib]
>
> 0x0000000c (INIT) 0x9f64
>
> 0x0000000d (FINI) 0xb74c
>
> 0x00000019 (INIT_ARRAY) 0x14000
>
> 0x0000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ) 4 (bytes)
>
> 0x0000001a (FINI_ARRAY) 0x14004
>
> 0x0000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ) 4 (bytes)
>
> 0x00000004 (HASH) 0x8168
>
> 0x00000005 (STRTAB) 0x8c04
>
> 0x00000006 (SYMTAB) 0x84c4
>
> 0x0000000a (STRSZ) 3806 (bytes)
>
> 0x0000000b (SYMENT) 16 (bytes)
>
> 0x00000015 (DEBUG) 0x0
>
> 0x00000003 (PLTGOT) 0x14134
>
> 0x00000002 (PLTRELSZ) 776 (bytes)
>
> 0x00000014 (PLTREL) REL
>
> 0x00000017 (JMPREL) 0x9c5c
>
> 0x00000011 (REL) 0x9c3c
>
> 0x00000012 (RELSZ) 32 (bytes)
>
> 0x00000013 (RELENT) 8 (bytes)
>
> 0x6ffffffe (VERNEED) 0x9bcc
>
> 0x6fffffff (VERNEEDNUM) 3
>
> 0x6ffffff0 (VERSYM) 0x9ae2
>
> 0x00000000 (NULL) 0x0

Please help me and guide me to fix it.
Thanks a lot,
Orian.

Comment: Just a guess, but it sounds like you're building with one version of Qt, and running with another version of Qt.